# Using images as input for D3.js

Tags: javascript, image-processing, d3.js

I'm trying to evaluate if D3.js is a suitable library for my upcoming project.

I need to produce certain diagrams of images (like PNG or anything else the browser supports with its `<image>` tag) but after some investigation I could not find any mechanism to use images as data input for visualizations.

Did I miss something and is it already implemented? Otherwise, is there some abstract easily implemented interface I could use for that and implement it on my own?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "image"? Are you talking about bitmaps or vector graphics (SVG)? In the former case you'd need some kind of metadata about the images to use it with d3. In the latter case you can modify it just like you would any other visualisation.

Comment: With image I mean raster images the browser supports as with in the `<image>` tag, like PNG. I want to process this image and create visualizations for it (diagrams).

Comment: Like this? http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#canvaspixelarray

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda: this looks promising, although it seems not supported by all relevant browsers. But it is definitely worth looking into and try it with D3.

Comment: I'm not aware of anybody having done this with d3, so I'm afraid you're probably on your own.

Comment: This example reads image data and uses it for input in a D3 visualization - is that what you're looking for? http://www.koalastothemax.com/

Comment: @nrabinowitz: A very interesting application. I think using the canvas 2D context is currently the only cross-browser solution available. But I'll keep searching. Thank you for the link!